# Gson Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT for type Byte[]

Tags: java, android, gson

I am serializing using json.net on the server side and I use Gson on the client side android app. I do not wish to make this change on the server side because I dot want to change every other platform just because I could not figure out how to do this on android.

So the problem is that my poco class has an object of type Byte[] named "key", but what I am receiving is the json object below.

```
"key":{  
         "$type":"Byte[]",
         "$value":"R3np9gckNMgH9uoqd9quAn7WfUs09Xa+gkETDSHKd9Y="
      }
```

When Gson tries to deserialize the object the following exception is thrown:

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 287 path $.classname.key
```

I imagine I will have to use an "adapter" like I did with dates shown below, but I am kinda stumped.

```
private static class DateTypeAdapter implements com.google.gson.JsonSerializer<Date>, JsonDeserializer<Date> {
        private final DateFormat dateFormat;

        private DateTypeAdapter() {
            dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss", Locale.US);
            dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        }

        @Override
        public synchronized JsonElement serialize(Date date, Type type,JsonSerializationContext jsonSerializationContext) {
            return new JsonPrimitive(dateFormat.format(date));
        }

        @Override
        public synchronized Date deserialize(JsonElement jsonElement, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext jsonDeserializationContext) {
            try {
                return dateFormat.parse(jsonElement.getAsString());
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                throw new JsonParseException(e);
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks for the help in advanced...

Edit code example:

```
public static <T> T deserialize(String in, Class<T> c)  {
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, new DateTypeAdapter()).create();
return gson.fromJson(in,c);
}
```

Json(Simplified):

```
{
   "$type":"Response",
   "classname":{
      "$type":"ClassName",
      "key":{
         "$type":"Byte[]",
         "$value":"R3np8gckNMgH9uoqd9quAn7WfUs08Xa+gkETDSHKd9Y="
      },
   },
   "success":true
}
```

POCO:

```
public class Response
{
    public ClassName ClassName;
}

public class ClassName
{
    public byte[] key;
}
```

Comment: could you please post code which is throwing exception? and also full json with beginning and closing brackets ( [ and/or { )

Comment: Can you post your model and how you are serialising json?

Comment: no stacktrace necessary. all that is needed is here and more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I suspected I needed an adapter to translate from the base64 "byte[]" to a real byte[]. This worked while other solutions I found did not.

```
private static Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(byte[].class, new ByteArrayAdapter()).create();

    private static class ByteArrayAdapter implements com.google.gson.JsonSerializer<byte[]>, JsonDeserializer<byte[]> {

            @Override
            public byte[] deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
                return Base64.decode(json.getAsJsonObject().get("$value").toString().getBytes(),Base64.DEFAULT);
            }

            @Override
            public JsonElement serialize(byte[] src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
                return new JsonPrimitive(Base64.encodeToString(src, Base64.NO_WRAP));
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your json output looks different. Normally array data is surrounded by [ ]. Your seems to be encoded (base64?) and does not represent json array. While your java class does expect array. That is the reason you are getting above error. Check your server code. It must be doing something.

I wrote sample code below. Look at the output.

```
import java.util.Date;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
import com.google.gson.internal.bind.DateTypeAdapter;

public class ByteArraySample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyClass m = new MyClass();
        String testStr = "This is test string";
        m.key = testStr.getBytes();

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, new DateTypeAdapter()).create();
        String json = gson.toJson(m);
        System.out.println("Created json: "+ json);

        MyClass created = gson.fromJson(json, MyClass.class);
        System.out.println("Created key: "+ new String(created.key));

    }

}

class MyClass {
    @SerializedName("key")
    public byte[] key;
}
```

output

```
Created json: {"key":[84,104,105,115,32,105,115,32,116,101,115,116,32,115,116,114,105,110,103]}
Created key: This is test string
```

Comment: I need to deserialize what I am being given.

Comment: @Theyouthis you need to know what is given. In your case its a simple string object so in your pojo, you need to define simple string object and not byte[]. Gson is not that intelligent :)

Comment: it is a byte[] on both sides, and only becomes a string during serialization from the server...

Comment: @Theyouthis Thats exactly what I am saying. Your server code might have custom serializer which emits encoded string along with class name ($type). Any normal json library will not do it by default. All Client side code sees is incoming json and there its defined as string so its failing.

Comment: .....So then I need a custom deserializer like the datetypeAdapter mentioned above(I'm already trying to figure this out)

Comment: I think so. But even before that you need to know the formula (logic) to convert that string back to Byte[]. Without that you wouldn't know what to do in custom serializer. Looking at your example, looks like base64 encoded.

Comment: I found out that json.net serializes byte[] like this by default, unfortunately I cannot change this and need to deserialize it.